# Wordpress: get_post_field() throws error like it's trying to redefine a function

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a function called `getNews()`.

I call `getNews()` like this:

```
<div class="wrapper" id="blog">
    <div class="blogPosts">
        <?PHP getNews($postPerPage, 0, $theme_link, $pageNum); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

The function works until it tries to get the article text from wordpress using `get_post_field()`.

```
function getNews($numPosts, $offset, $theme_link, $pageNum) {
    $offset = $numPosts * $pageNum;
    $recent_args = array('numberposts' => $numPosts, 'offset' => $offset,);
    $articles = wp_get_recent_posts($recent_args);
    foreach($articles as $article){
        $article_id = $article['ID'];
        ...
        echo $article_text = get_post_field('post_content', $article_id);
        ...
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get the error saying `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare getNews() (previously declared in /homepages/30/d545089862/htdocs/VintageTroubleMusic/wp-content/plugins/enhanced-text-widget/enhanced-text-widget.php(57)`

For some reason, it's running my loop twice.

Any advice?

**EDIT**

I'm including the full code here:  This is written inside of an "Enhanced Text widget" inside of a page.

```
<?PHP
    $theme_link = "/wp-content/themes/thestory-child/";
    $pageNum = $_GET['pa'];
    $postPerPage = 27;
    $qry_numPosts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Ykcfdlqhposts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post'") or die(mysql_error());
    $numPosts = mysql_num_rows($qry_numPosts);              
    $numPages = ceil($numPosts/$postPerPage) . " pages";
    if(!$pageNum){
        $pageNum = 0;   
    }
?>
<!-- START OF THE BODY HERE -->
<h3 class="widget-title" style="float:left;">Headlines</h3>
<div class="wrapper" id="paginate1">
    <?PHP paginate($numPosts, $numPages); ?>
</div>
<div class="wrapper" id="blog">
    <div class="blogPosts">
        <?PHP getNews($postPerPage, 0, $theme_link, $pageNum); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper" id="paginate2">
    <?PHP paginate($numPosts, $numPages); ?>
</div>
```

And inside of the `functions.php` page

```
function getNews($numPosts, $offset, $theme_link, $pageNum) {
$offset = $numPosts * $pageNum;
$recent_args = array('numberposts' => $numPosts, 'offset' => $offset,);
$articles = wp_get_recent_posts($recent_args);
foreach($articles as $article){
    $article_id = $article['ID'];
    $article_link = get_permalink($article_id);
    $article_length = 350;
    $article_background = get_the_post_thumbnail($article_id);
    $article_title = get_post_meta( $article_id, 'short_title', true );
    $article_text = "test";
    $article_text = get_post_field('post_content', $article_id);
    //$article_text = get_post_field('post_content', $article_id);
    //$article_text = strip_tags($article_text);
    //$article_text_length = strlen($article_text);
    /*
    if($article_text_length >= $article_length) {
        $article_text_pos = strpos($article_text, " ", $article_length);
        $article_text = substr($article_text, 0, $article_text_pos)."... ";
    }
    */
    ?>

    <div class="article">
        <?PHP //Get the article image
        if (!$article_background) {
            $rand = rand(1, 5);
            $img = $theme_link . "images/img" . $rand . ".jpg";
        } else {
            $img = explode('src="', $article_background);
            $img = explode(".jpg", $img[1]);
            $img = $img[0] . ".jpg";
        }?>   
        <a href="<?= $article_link; ?>">
            <div class="article__image" style="background-image: url('<?= $img; ?>');"></div>
            <div class="article__title"><?= $article_title; ?></div>
        </a>

        <div class="article__details">
            <div class="article-text">
                <?= $article_text; ?> 
            </div>
            <a href="<?= $article_link; ?>">READ MORE</a>
        </div>
    </div>
 <? }
}
function paginate($numPosts, $numPages) {
?>
<div class="page">
    <span>Page:</span><?PHP
        $i = 0;
        while($i < $numPages){
            $i++;
            if($i == $pageNum){
                echo '<a href="?pa='.$i.'"><span style="background-color:transparent; text-decoration:underline; color:white; cursor:default;">'.$i.'</span></a>';
            } else {
                echo "<a href='?pa=".$i."'><span>".$i."</span></a>";    
            }
        }
    ?>
</div>
<?
}
```

Comment: Have you tested <?PHP echo getNews($postPerPage, 0, $theme_link, $pageNum); ?> ?- Can you post the full error path?

Comment: I just tried echoing the getNews function, but it's hanging up on the $article_text.  I've just update the path to show the plugin path that's messing up

Comment: Where is getNews defined?

Comment: @aynber, Technically it's defined in an "Enhanced text field" inside of a "page" in wordpress.

Comment: just define it in a functions.php and rename the function to see if error still occur on get_post_field .

Comment: Just wanted to clarify, you are not defining the function twice in two different places, the theme and then the plugin?

Comment: @koded, just tried this, similar result.  It feels like it's repeating itself somewhere.  Although, this will be a LOT easier to edit.

Comment: @David.J, Correct, I am not defining it any other place.  Though, after Koded's suggestion, I have it defined ONLY in functions.php.  I can tell it's running from there when I make changes and tests, but the single line with `get_post_field()` is messing it all up.

Comment: so you get a different error now relating to get_post_field()?

Comment: @David.J, Oddly enough, I'm not getting any error now. When I inspect the code, I see what's basically almost an infinite loop: http://imgur.com/FZVEjHC